# Create Folders and Subfolders with os. Code improvement

Tags: python, operating-system, directory, subdirectory

I want to automate some stuff I am currently working on. I am writing a function at the moment, which is automatically creating me all directories and subdirectories. I feel like this is veeeery hard-coded.. I would appreciate if someone could look over this and tell me where and how I could improve my code.

Thanks in advance!

```
def create_dirs(MD,home_team,away_team,info):
    folders = ["Stats","Press","Info"]
    gamefolder = (home_team+" vs "+away_team+" ("+info+")")
    infofolder = ("Info-Pictures "+"("+info+")")
    path = (r"C:\path\to\destination\")
    newpath =(r"C:\path\to\destination\\"+MD)
    gamedir = (r"C:\path\to\destination\\"+MD+r"\\"+gamefolder)
    infodir = (r"C:\path\to\destination\\"+MD+r"\\"+infofolder)

    try:
        os.chdir(path)
        if not os.path.exists(MD):
            os.makedirs(MD)
    except OSError:
        print('Error: Creating directory:' + MD)
    try:
        os.chdir(newpath)
        os.mkdir(gamefolder)
        os.mkdir(infofolder)
    except OSError:
        print('Error: Creating directory:' + gamefolder)
    try:
        for folder in folders:
            os.mkdir(os.path.join(gamefolder,folder))
    except OSError:
        print('Error: Creating directory. Directory/ies already exists')
    try:
        os.chdir(infodir)
        os.mkdir("Before")
        os.mkdir("After")
    except OSError:
        print('Error: Creating directory. Directory/ies already exist')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use os.makedirs:

```
import os
os.makedirs("C:\\Users\\<username>\\Desktop\\asd\\asd\\asd\\asd")
```

It will create a folders and subfolders

Comment: yes it does but it is not generating multiple sub folders.. so this answer is not what I am looking for